# Faceted search using solr-node

Tags: node.js, solr

I am trying to search my documents indexed on solr 6.6.5 using facet search in node.js with the solr-node module. But when I add facet=on&facet.query=: I get an HTTP 400 response from solr-node.

```html
var client = new SolrNode({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8983',
    core: 'IRF18P4',
    protocol: 'http',
    debugLevel: 'ERROR' // log4js debug level paramter
});

var delhiCount = client.query.q('*:*&facet.query=city:delhi&facet=on');

// Search documents using strQuery
client.search(delhiCount, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return;
    }
    console.log('Response:', result.response);
 });
```

But if I try to open the same URL printed in my terminal, it works. Any idea on what could be going wrong here?

```html
PS C:\Users\aarti\OneDrive\Documents\IR\Project4\gentelella-master\gentelella-master> node index.js
[2018-12-02 19:16:02.533] [ERROR] sole-node - Body {
  url:
   'http://localhost:8983/solr/IRF18P4/select?q=*%3A*%26facet%3Don%26facet.query%3Dcity%3Adelhi&wt=json',
  status: 400,
  statusText: 'Bad Request',
  headers:
   Headers {
     _headers:
      { 'cache-control': [Array],
        pragma: [Array],
        expires: [Array],
        'last-modified': [Array],
        etag: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        connection: [Array] } },
  ok: false,
  body:
   PassThrough {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 1 },
        length: 280,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: null,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: true,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        emitClose: true,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     _events:
      { prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
        unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
        drain: [Function: pipeOnDrainFunctionResult],
        error: [Function: onerror],
        close: [Function],
        finish: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _transformState:
      { afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
        needTransform: true,
        transforming: false,
        writecb: null,
        writechunk: null,
        writeencoding: 'buffer' } },
  bodyUsed: false,
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  _raw: [],
  _abort: false }
Solr server error: 400
```

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question. It will make it far easier for others to read it and try to help

Answer (score 0):

Your URL being printed in Output is Wrong.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/IRF18P4/select?q=*%3A*%26facet%3Don%26facet.query%3Dcity%3Adelhi&wt=json
```

Above should look like,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/IRF18P4/select?q=*:*&facet=on&facet.query=city:delhi&wt=json
```

And your code should be,

```
var delhiCount = client.query
    .q('*:*') 
    .addParams({
         facet: 'true',
         facet.query: "city:delhi"
         wt: 'json',
     });
```

For more help refer,
Resource : https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-node

Comment: Hi Raghu, the : is just being replaced by %3A

Text
Text queries are similar to what one would find on the SOLR Core UI, EX:
From the URL: http://localhost:8080/solr/products/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json
The Query would be:
*:*&wt=json
NOTE: url decoded ':' from %3A.

It has been stated on npjms, https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-node

Comment: : being replaced with %3A is correct. but your line 'client.query.q('*:*&facet.query=city:delhi&facet=on');'  sending facet query as part of q parameter. Replace this line with lines given in my answer as we want to send facet query as separate parameter.